# How can you override the defaults configure options for a pecl installed package

Tags: php, lua, pecl

I'm currently having issues installing the PECL LUA package due to a configure failure with:

```
pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/lua-0.9.4
```

Giving

```
...
checking for lua support... yes, shared
checking for lua in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the lua distribution - lua.h should be in <lua-   dir>/include/
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/lua/configure' failed
```

Having looked at the tarball it seems the configure script will accept a "--with-lua" override to pass the known location of the lua headers. However it's entirely non-obvious how you can pass this information down using the pecl installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems there is broken configure magic in the package. In the end I had to hardwire a few paths:

```
ln -s /usr/include/lua /usr/include/lua5.1
ln -s /usr/lib/liblua5.1.a liblua.a
ln -s /usr/include/lua/* /usr/include
```

Was enough to get the compiler through.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem. And I cannot finde the liblua.a file after installing lua: apt-get install lua5.1 liblua5.1-0 liblua5.1-0-dev

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem on ubuntu:17.10 with lua5.3 and php7.1 by

```
pecl download lua
tar xvzf lua-2.0.4.tgz
cd lua-2.0.4
phpize
./configure --with-lua-version=5.3
make
make install
```

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, every `configure` script allows you to pass custom `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`. This allows you to do the following:

```
CFLAGS="-I/path/to/lua/include" LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/lua/lib" ./configure
```

Use `CXXFLAGS` if the source is C++.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems CFLAGS gets squashed via the "pecl install" call.